# Ruby: Database Authentication Module

Tags: ruby, meta-programming, modules

I have created a module that validates the credentials against different databases.

```
module Authentication

  DATABASES = %w[mysql mssql oracle].freeze

  DATABASES.each do |database|
    define_method("#{database}_connect") do |args|
      client = case database
               when 'mysql' then Mysql2::Client.new args.merge(ssl_mode: :disabled)
               when 'mssql' then TinyTds::Client.new args
               when 'oracle' then OCI8.new(args[:username], args[:password], "//#{args[:host]}:#{args[:port]}/#{args[:service_name]}")
               end
      case database
      when 'mysql', 'oracle' then true
      when 'mssql' then client.active?
      end
    end
  end

  def database_authentication_success?(database:, host:, port:, service_name:, username:, password:)
    options = {host: host, port: port, service_name: service_name, username: username, password: password}
    case database
    when 'mysql' then mysql_connect(options)
    when 'mssql' then mssql_connect(options)
    when 'oracle' then oracle_connect(options)
    end
  end
end
```

Please let me know, how can it be improved?

Answer (score 1):

What is the use case and rationale for this module? I can see what it does, but I'm struggling to understand why I'd want to do it.

The fact that you have three almost identical `case` statements to drive the behaviour is a 'code smell'. In most other OO languages you'd use inheritance or an interface and a factory method to determine which subclass of an object to create (with a single `case` statement). In that case, the objective is to abstract away the differences between connecting to the databases behind an interface (which is what you seem to be trying to do in method `database_authentication_success?`). But the metaprogramming code generates explicitly-named methods for connecting to each type of database, which seems to do the opposite and makes it harder to use.